# Wine changing screen resolution, game stays in original resolution

Tags: nvidia, wine, resolution, games, playonlinux

When I start Stalker in Wine it will change the Desktop resolution to a much lower value. Normal is 1920x1080.

The game itself does not even fit on the screen completely at that point.

Here is a screenshot [image: screenshot]

How can I make the game play in Fullscreen in 1920x1080?

I am using PlayonLinux on Ubuntu 14.10. GPU is GTX560TI

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>f4</kbd> on your keyboard then the resolution should change (if it doesnt then press <kbd>f4</kbd> again) then launch the game. It worked for me. When you're done playing, close the game and press <kbd>f4</kbd> again.